# Python pyautogui and double quotes

Tags: python, pyautogui

I try to type in double quotes ('"') with pyautogui.write() function but what I get is the caracter 3 instead !
How to type in those double quotes ??

Comment: That must be a problem with your keyboard or keyboard driver, try typing double quotes in notepad and then copy paste them to your editor. Or if you are unable to type double quotes into notepad as well, you just copy them from somewhere on the internet and paste them in your editor. `"  "`

Comment: @Someone I was able to recreate the problem, when having CAPS LOCK activated while executing the function. Otherwise it writes " just normal.

Comment: So, then problem solved, just disable the caps lock

Comment: No issue with my keyboard! Double quotes are normally displayed everywhere! I've just made a test with pynput's keyboard.type() function and the SAME string passed to it is well displayed ( " included). So the problem really comes from pyautogui.write() function!!!

Answer (score 1):

That's because python doesn't accept inverted commas in strings. To do that you'll have to do this:

```
from pyautogui import *
press("\"")
```

OR

```
from pyautogui import *
keyDown("shift")
press("'")
keyUp("shift")
```

OR

```
from pyautogui import *
typewrite("\"")
```